# Compare pixels as fast as possible

Tags: python, image, performance, pixel

I am trying to find exact RGB on my screen with python and compare them as fast as possible.
The code uses PIL ImageGrab to get the pixels on the screen. Is it possible to make it faster?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
px = ImageGrab.grab().load()

for y in range(pointY, rangeY, 1):
    for x in range(pointX, rangeX, 1):
        color = px[x, y] # Screen pixel
        img = pix[0,0] # First pixel of my image

        if img[0] != color[0] or img[1] != color[1] or img[2] != color[2]:
            continue
        else:
            # Compare the whole image
```

Comment: If you are looking for speed, I recommend using openCV and one of it's many methods for finding difference of two images. Any python code that iterates through all pixels will be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy to compare the colors.

This will return a 2D array the size of the screen, where every occurrence of your color is marked with True.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
screen_grab = np.asarray(ImageGrab.grab())
my_color = np.asarray(pix[0,0])

# returns 2D array of comparisons
result = np.all(screen_grab==my_color, axis=-1)
```

If you just want to check if it contains the color then do

```py
# returns true if the screen contains your color anywhere
result_any = np.any(result)
```

If you want to get the coordinates of the matching pixels you can do

```py
# returns coordinates of the pixels that match
result_idx = np.argwhere(result)
```

Comment: My code is exactly like yours and I'm getting 'false' as a result even though my screen has the pixel color in it and I'm also getting an empty array. Idk why, any idea?

Comment: I edited the answer, sorry about that.

Comment: Tysm, it's working now. The only problem I found is that, if my image has an alpha value, it will give me an error. Can I make it ignore the alpha value with numpy? I thought about making a 'for loop' to remove from the array but that is probably slower.

Comment: Glad it works now!
`no_alpha = np.asarray(img)[:,:,:2]` should do the trick, if the image is in RGBA format.